# How to not print repeating words for each row in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm still getting used to Python! I just need a little help with this: In my program there are two csv files, one named "testclaims" and one named "notinlist." For writer3 I have the program printing each word of each row in a new csv in its own row. For example if the row in testclaims says

```
The boy fell and the boy got hurt
```

It outputs:

```
The
boy
fell
and
the
boy
got
hurt
```

But what I don't want it printing a word again if it repeats in the same row. I want the output to say:

```
The
boy
fell
and
the
got
hurt
```

I've been trying to do this for a little bit now playing around the Counter and frequency but can't figure it out. If you guys could help me out, that'd be great! Here's my code:

```
import csv

with open("testclaims.csv") as file1, open("masterlist.csv") as file2,
    open("stopwords.csv") as file3,\
    open("output.csv", "wb+") as file4, open("output2.csv", "wb+") as file5:
    writer = csv.writer(file4)
    writer2 = csv.writer(file5)
    key_words = [word.strip() for word in file2.readlines()]
    stop_words = [word.strip() for word in file3.readlines()]
    internal_stop_words = [' a ', ' an ', ' and ', 'as ', ' at ', ' be ', 'ed ',
          'ers ', ' for ',\
          ' he ', ' if ', ' in ', ' is ', ' it ', ' of ', ' on ', ' to ', 'her ', 'hers '\
          ' do ', ' did ', ' a ', ' b ', ' c ', ' d ', ' e ', ' f ', ' g ', ' h ', ' i ',\
          ' j ', ' k ', ' l ', ' m ', 'n ', ' n', ' nc ' ' o ', ' p ', ' q ', ' r ', ' s ',\
          ' t ', ' u ', ' v ', ' w ', ' x ', ' y ', 'z ', ',', '"', 'ers ', ' th ', ' gc ',\
                   ' so ', ' ot ', ' ft ', ' ow ', ' ir ', ' ho ', ' er ', ]
    for row in file1:
        row = row.strip()
        row = row.lower()

        for stopword in internal_stop_words:
            if stopword in row:
                row = row.replace(stopword," ")

        for key in key_words:
            if key in row:
                writer.writerow([key, row])

        for word in row.split(): #This Part Here!
            writer3.writerow([word])

        if not any(key in row for key in key_words):
            writer2.writerow([row])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple using an OrderedDict...

```
>>> import collections
>>> print "\n".join(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys("The boy fell and the boy got hurt".split()).keys())
The
boy
fell
and
the
got
hurt
```

Comment: This prints it within the shell, correct? I'm having it outputted into a new csv file.

Comment: It was just an example of getting unique words in the correct order.  Instead of printing it to stdout, you can do anything you like with it.

Answer (score 1):

use `set()`

```
row = 'The boy fell and the boy got hurt'

s = set()

for word in row.split():
    if word not in s:
        s.add(word)
        #print word
        writer3.writerow([word])
```

Comment: you lose the ordering

Comment: I think it is supposed to be: `if word not in mySet(): print word; mySet.add(word)`

Comment: @GauravJain: It would be more beneficial to the OP to actually show creating a set outside of a loop over the `word`s, checking, printing, adding to set.  As it is now the code certainly won't do what is being asked.

Comment: Hey guys I appreciate the help! But this isn't being printed. It's being outputted into it's own csv file, that's what the writer3.writerow(word) is for

Comment: I just provided the logic and you are saying itsn't being printed? 
see this: http://ideone.com/9dGScU

Comment: @GauravJain What I mean is my intent is not the print this. My intent is to output it into a new csv file with each word in its own row. minus the repeating words for each row. I don't want it printed, but outputted into a new csv

Comment: then use `writer3.writerow(word)` instead of `print word` !
what's the problem?

Comment: It didn't work, I'll keep trying, but thanks guys. @GauravJain